# Tab to complete filenames with :find at an arbitrary depth

Tags: autocompletion, load, filesystem

**Notes**:

- I have `set path=$PWD/**` in my `.vimrc`
- I am using Vim 7.3

Often times, I am sitting with Vim open at the root of my project and I enter `:find somef<Tab>` to find and open a file at an arbitrary depth. This *always* works when I am sitting at the project root with no file open.

When I have a file open, however, I can't just type `:find anotherfi<Tab>` to get a list of possible options - Vim gives me a quick `:find anotherfi...` and then leaves me with `:find anotherfi`.

How can I make tab completion with `:find` work with my `path` when I am visiting any file as it does when I am sitting at the root with nothing open?

Comment: Perhaps version specific. Works fine on 7.4.617, with `vim -u NONE`, and after `:set wc=<Tab>`, `:set path=$PWD/**`.

Comment: I will check, I also just noticed that the path is changing when I visit a file.. Is there a way to keep the path at what I was when I opened vim?

Comment: Perhaps a plugin? My `path` remains the same.

Comment: It's definitely `vim-classpath`.. Will confirm.

Comment: You don't need `$PWD/**`, `**` is enough. Also, `.,**` is more useful because it lets you find files in the directory of the current file even if it is not under the working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by a changing path due to Tim Pope's `vim-classpath` plugin. To fix the issue, simply remove that plugin.

To confirm this, either run vim with `vim -u NONE` and manually run `:set path=$PWD/**` to test, or temporarily remove the plugin.

If you require the plugin this may not be a viable option.

Comment: The help text for path says it's recommended that you append instead of assign, so if the plugin is overwriting the path, perhaps it should be treated as a bug and a issue raised on Github.

Comment: I raised the bug, but it was closed almost immediately and I was fairly satisfied with the reasoning. If you or anyone else feels it should be reopened and is affected by it feel free to comment, the issue shouldn't be too hard to find on GitHub